# How to set datacontext for the Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I 'm learning wpf through mvvm. I have a ViewModel which is binded to the view through the window datacontext

Window.Xaml:

```
xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:UploadFileToDB.ViewModel"

  <Window.DataContext>
        <Converter:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

The application works fine when all the methods are present inside the ViewModel Class.

Now I have a datagrid in the view, for populating the datagrid I have created a seperate class called populatedatagrid under the ViewModel namespace.

**pseudocode which is not working :**

```
   namespace UploadFileToDB.ViewModel
{
    public class PopulateDatagrid
    {
        public ObservableCollection<datagridmodel> modelclasswithcombobox
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        DataSet ds;
        public void comboboxdata()
        { //This code populate the observable collection}
        }
    }
        public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            PopulateDatagrid populatedatagridwithobservablecollection = new PopulateDatagrid();
            public ViewModel()
            {
                populatedatagridwithobservablecollection.combobxdata();
            //Calling the above class method here to populate data. But this throws the error that BindingExpression path error that ModelClassWithcombobox property not found on object ViewModel
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code is not working correctly due to the binding expression error.

**pseudocode which is working :**

```
   namespace UploadFileToDB.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public ObservableCollection<datagridmodel> modelclasswithcombobox
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        DataSet ds;
        public void comboboxdata()
        { //This code populate the observable collection}
        }
            public ViewModel()
            {
                comboboxdata();
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code works perfectly without any issue. On my understanding since I have mapped only ViewModel class on datacontext. The xaml can't able to find the observable collection which is present in the other class.

Can anyone help me on how to acheive segreagration of class and provide solution to above scenario

Edit : As requested window.xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="UploadFileToDB.Window1"
    xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:UploadFileToDB.ViewModel" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:UploadFileToDB.ViewModel"

    Title="Window1" Height="400" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Converter:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1500*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Tabcontrol>
<TabItem Header="Re Assign">
     <StackPanel>

                        <DataGrid  Height="150" x:Name="datagrid1" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" Width="507" Margin="150,-35,20,79" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <DataGrid.Style>
                                <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                                    <Setter  Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding modelclasswithcombobox}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.Style>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
 </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You should place the observable collection in the viewmodel.  Your other class PopulateDatagrid can still have access the viewmodel properties  if you pass in a reference to the viewmodel to the class constructor (look up Dependancy Injection)

Comment: _The above code works perfectly without any issue._ If you have worked code, why do you want something else?

Comment: @Rekshino Just a part of learning. the question is about whether i want to write all the logic in viewmodel. Because writing a seperate logic in another class and calling that logic in viewmodel doesn't work for me. Also can you explain me why my first psedocode fails.

Comment: Why one ore another doesn't work is only possible to say, if there is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E.g. you don't post any XAML code, which can be the reason, why the first code doesn't work.

Comment: @Rekshino as requested I have  posted my xaml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **only bind to the properties**, **not to the fields**. So for it works you should use something like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PopulateDatagrid Populatedatagridwithobservablecollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection)
            {
                _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Populatedatagridwithobservablecollection));
            }
        }
    }
    private PopulateDatagrid _populatedatagridwithobservablecollection = new PopulateDatagrid();;
}
```